# Apply if-else statement on a dictionary using django-templates

Tags: django, templates

In a django - webapp I am classifying between two classes of images i.e. Ants and Bees
I have returned the dictionary to the templates(index.html)

```
        context={
            'ant':("%.2f" % predictions[0]),
            'bee': ("%.2f" % predictions[1]),
        }
```

> when applying this

```
 {% for key , value in pred.items %}
<p>{{key}}: {{value}}%</p>

{% endfor %}
```

[image]

i got this which is pretty much what i wanted to display now i want to display the one with greater probability how do i do it ?
I cannot access elements of the dictionary inside if else statement , though i tried doing this

```
 {% for key, value in pred.items %}
    {% if value.0 > value.1 %}        
        <p>Result : {{value.0}}</p>
    {% elif value.0 < value.1 %}
        <p>Result: {{key}}</p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data structure does not look very dynamic and flexible, you could do it the following static way:

```
Result:
{% if pred.ant > pred.bee %}
    Ant: {{ pred.ant }}
{% elif pred.ant < pred.bee %}
    Bee: {{ pred.bee }}
{% else %}
    Ant: {{ pred.ant }}
    Bee: {{ pred.bee }}
{% endif %}
```